# Which is the right way to initialize a UI theme?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to initialize my theme. using this `UIManager.initFirstTheme()` gives an error `method not found`.

**Note** I am working on `NetBeans` and latest codename one.

Comment: What's the exact error? Notice `initFirstTheme()` accepts a string path to the res file (without the .res extension) did you use that correctly?